# Is there a way to have different JavaScript library versions on different branches in Git?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, express

I am trying to upgrade a repo that currently uses a library that is in version 3. I want to be able to create a branch (BranchB) that is specific to updating this library to version 4. So I tried changing the package.json on BranchB to use v4 and did an `npm install` in order to get the correct version *on this new branch*.

I run the tests and they fail. Perfect.

Now when I switch back to master, I would prefer that the library version being used is set back to v3. Is there a Git workflow to make this possible? Or will I keep having to `npm install` every time I want the appropriate branch to have the correct corresponding library versions?

Comment: "I run the tests and they fail"... are you talking about unit tests (Karma, etc.)? What specifically about the project fails? Is v4 of whatever library you're using backwards compatible with your code?

Comment: Also, unless you put the node modules themselves into the git repo (which is usually not recommended), I don't see how you could avoid reinstalling your packages every time. Unless you remotely link to the different versions of the libraries separately, decoupling the branch from the dependencies (much like how one would use a remote CDN to use a specific version of jQuery in their project, for example).

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade Express from version ~3 to version ~4. One of the things they changed was app.locals is no longer a function but is instead an object. This causes all my unit tests to fail. In hindsight, that statement in my question was unnecessary. I wanted to show that on one branch I had v4 and it was working properly. I now want to make sure that my master branch stays clean -- which therefore would require v3.

Answer (score 0):

One possible strategy, albeit a bit clunky, is to clone the repo twice to different folders - one with the older library, one with the newer. Then just pretend that you've got split personality and edit the projects as two different programmers :)

As I said, it's clunky but it's better than constantly installing the libraries.